# Change attribute depending on Select Option

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to make the  disappear when Other Countries is selected.

This is my HTML

```
<select class="country" name="country">
     <option value="Portugal">Portugal</option>
     <option value="OtherCountries">Other Countries</option>
</select>

<tr id="this">
     <td valign="middle"><label class="registration">VAT (23%)</label></td>
     <td valign="middle"></td>
     <td valign="middle"><input class="input_form_reg" name="vat_price" type="text"></td>
</tr>
```

And this is my script (which I found here on stackoverflow)

```
<script>
    $("select").on('change', function() {
        var sel = $("select").val();
        if (sel=='Portugal') {
            $("#this").css("display", "inline");
        }else if (sel=='OtherCountries') {
            $("#this").css("display", "none");
        }
    });
</script>
```

And I don't know why but it isn't working, it just stays there.

Comment: $("#this").css("display", "inline") is jQuery (or another javascript library). Did you load that? Are there any (javascript) errors in your browser console?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this code

```
<select class="country" name="country">
                <option value="Portugal">Portugal</option>
                <option value="OtherCountries">Other Countries</option>
</select>
<table>
          <tr id="this">
            <td valign="middle"><label class="registration">VAT (23%)</label></td>
            <td valign="middle"></td>
            <td valign="middle"><input class="input_form_reg" name="vat_price" type="text"></td>
          </tr>
          </table>
<script>
    $(".country").change(function() {
        var sel = $(this).val();
        if (sel=='Portugal') {
        $("#this").show();
        }
        if (sel=='OtherCountries') {
        $("#this").hide();
        }
    });
</script>
```

Comment: This solution is fine for above OP but if there are Portugal, Germany and many countries then this solution is not fine and generic.

Answer (score 3):

try

your html is invalid, wrap the tr inside table

```
<table>
          <tr id="this">
            <td valign="middle"><label class="registration">VAT (23%)</label></td>
            <td valign="middle"></td>
            <td valign="middle"><input class="input_form_reg" name="vat_price" type="text"></td>
          </tr>
    </table>
```

### [Working demo](http://jsfiddle.net/srsggcrz/1/)

JS

```
$("select").on('change', function () {
     if (this.value == 'Portugal') {
         $("#this").show();
     } else {
         $("#this").hide();
     }

 });
```

---

```
 $("select").on('change', function () {
     $("#this").toggle(this.value != "OtherCountries");
 });
```

### [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/srsggcrz/2/)

Comment: These are just shorts of my html. the <tr> is inside the table.

Comment: @White8Tiger Why on earth you chose `this` as an id to that `tr` element?

Comment: @Bala Chandran.V : My code is completely wrong.. i got confused with `$("#this")`. May be you could suggest him with `.toggle(true/false)`

Comment: @White8Tiger I agree that is only going to end in tears :'(

Answer (score 0):

First change the  ID to another one more explicit like "vat" or something, and try this:

```
$('.country').change(function(){

  if($(this).val() == "OtherCountries"){
    $("#vat").hide();
  }else{
    $("#vat").show();
  }

 });
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use show/hide instead of using css() method.

Try this:

```js
$(".country").on('change', function() {
  
  if($(this).val()=="OtherCountries"){
    $("#this").hide();
  }else{
    $("#this").show();
  }
 
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select class="country" name="country">
         <option value="Portugal">Portugal</option>
         <option value="OtherCountries">Other Countries</option>
    </select>
    <table id="this">
    <tr>
         <td valign="middle"><label class="registration">VAT (23%)</label></td>
         <td valign="middle"></td>
         <td valign="middle"><input class="input_form_reg" name="vat_price" type="text"></td>
    </tr>
  </table>
```

Answer (score 0):

Table tag was missing in your HTML due to which it was not identifying table row with ID. I have corrected the code. Please take a look at the code given below.

```
<select class="country" name="country">
     <option value="Portugal">Portugal</option>
     <option value="OtherCountries">Other Countries</option>
</select>
<table>
<tr id="this">
     <td valign="middle"><label class="registration">VAT (23%)</label></td>
     <td valign="middle"></td>
     <td valign="middle"><input class="input_form_reg" name="vat_price" type="text"></td>
</tr>
</table>
<script>
    $("select").on('change', function() {
        var sel = $("select").val();
        if (sel=='Portugal') {
            $("#this").css("display", "block");
        }else if (sel=='OtherCountries') {
            $("#this").css("display", "none");
        }
    });
</script>
```